# HubSpot form script is throwing the Error: reCAPTCHA placeholder element must be an element or id

Tags: html, next.js, hubspot

I'm embedding a HubSpot form in a Next.js site and it's showing up properly but I'm getting the error: `Unhandled Runtime Error Error: reCAPTCHA placeholder element must be an element or id`

Here's the code

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js";
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    script.addEventListener("load", () => {
      if ((window as any).hbspt) {
        // casting as "any" is needed because TypeScript will throw an error without it
        (window as any).hbspt.forms.create({
          // casting as "any" is needed because TypeScript will throw an error without it
          portalId: "my-portal-id",
          formId: "my-form-id",
          target: "#hubspotForm",
        });
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

And in the body

```html
<div id="hubspotForm" />
```

Comment: I have exactly this issue and have temporarily solved it with https://github.com/snelsi/next-hubspot